# How can I use papaparse on Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, csv, papaparse

I have been trying to get `papaparse` running on `nodejs` for a very long time now and I keep failing. I want to try to load my local CSV and then give this `papaparse`? How to do that? My code does not work.

```
import papa from "papaparse";
import fs from "fs";

export const convertCSV = async (res: Response) => {
  const file = await fs.createReadStream("../files/test.csv");
  papa.parse(file, {
    header: true,
    complete: function (results, file) {
      console.log("Complete", results.data.length, "records.");
    },
  });
};
```

`results.data.length` is always `0`.

My CSV file is located in the files folder,  which is located in the src folder:

```
src/files/test.csv
```

Comment: How do I read it as a string?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Papaparse README](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/blob/master/README.md#papa-parse-for-node), it supports Node in this way:

> Papa Parse can parse a [Readable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) instead of a [File](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) when used in Node.js environments (in addition to plain strings). In this mode, `encoding` must, if specified, be a Node-supported character encoding. The `Papa.LocalChunkSize`, `Papa.RemoteChunkSize`, `download`, `withCredentials` and `worker` config options are unavailable.

> Papa Parse can also parse in a node streaming style which makes `.pipe` available. Simply pipe the [Readable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) to the stream returned from  `Papa.parse(Papa.NODE_STREAM_INPUT, options)`. The `Papa.LocalChunkSize`, `Papa.RemoteChunkSize`, `download`, `withCredentials`, `worker`, `step` and `complete` config options are unavailable. To register a callback with the stream to process data, use the `'data'` event like so: `stream.on('data', callback)` and to signal the end of stream, use the `'end'` event like so: `stream.on('end', callback)`.

Comment: One important caveat they don't mention - do not try and use `@types/papaparse` as it will refer to all the `DOM` libraries for the calls that are not supported in node and break your build. Old school `require` works just fine.

Comment: @OlyDungey will require give me the types ?

Comment: @Nathaniel yes it will but you will not to 'require' the relevant ones

Comment: @OlyDungey sorry i don't get, can you explain a bit further please

Answer (score 2):

As Erick says in their comment, [the download option is not supported by Node](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/blob/master/README.md#papa-parse-for-node). However, it does tell us the Node interface accepts a `ReadableStream` instead of a `File`.

This works for me:

```
Papa.parse(fs.createReadStream("sample/result.csv"), {
    complete: function(results) {
        console.log(results["data"]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, the problem is in the file path. `fs.createReadStream` needs an absolute path, or a path that's relative to the root of your project.

Assuming this is the project structure:

```
files/
  - test.csv
src/
  - convert-csv.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

Then you can use a path that's relative to the root: `'./files/test.csv'`,
or if you really want to use a path that's relative to the file then you can use `path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'files', 'test.csv')`.

See [NodeJS docs for path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths), it will use the path segments to resolve an absolute path for you.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue with papa-parse, the docs weren't very clear. Inspired by [Toshino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65902545/4211551)

```js
import Papa from 'papaparse';
import { Readable } from 'stream';

export const parseCsvFromReadable = async (
  readable: Readable,
): Promise<Papa.ParseResult<unknown>> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Papa.parse(readable, {
      complete: results => {
        if (results.errors.length > 0) {
          reject(new Error(JSON.stringify(results.errors)));
        }
        resolve(results);
      },
      error: error => reject(error),
      header: true,
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To get streaming working on Nodejs on a Mac, this worked for me:

Usage:
**% node this-file.mjs < csv-file.csv**

```
/* Documentation
   https://www.papaparse.com/docs#config
   https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/blob/master/README.md#papa-parse-for-node
*/

import Papa from 'papaparse'

Papa.parse(process.stdin, {
  header: true,
  step: function(results) {
    process.stdout.write(`${JSON.stringify(results.data)}\n`)
  },
})
```